# Question regarding role-playing dimension

Tags: data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling

I hope you can be helpful in answering one question in regards to role-playing dimensions.

When using views for a role playing dimension, Does it then matter which view is referred to later in the analysis. Especially, when sorting on the role playing dimension, can this be done no matter which view is used?

Hope the question is clear enough. If not, let me know and I will elaborate.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean you have created a view similar to "SELECT * FROM DIM" for each role the Dim plays? If that's all you've done then you could use any of these views in a subsequent SQL statement that joins the DIM to a FACT table - but obviously if you use the "wrong" view it's going to be very confusing for anyone trying to read your SQL (or you trying to understand what've you've written in 3 months time!)

For example, if you have a fact table with keys OrderDate and ShipDate that both reference your DateDim then you could create vwOrderDate and vwShipDate. You could then join FACT.OrderDate to vwShipDate and FACT.ShipDate to vwOrderDate and it will make no difference to the actual resultset your query produces (apart from, possibly, column names).

However, unless the applicable attributes are very different for different roles, I really wouldn't bother creating views for role-playing Dims as it's an unnecessary overhead and just going to cause confusion to anyone you've given access to at this level of the DB (who presumably have pretty strong SQL skills to be given this level of access?).

If you are trying to make life easier for end-users then either create these types of "views" in the models of the BI tool(s) they are using - and not directly in the DB - or, if they are being given access to the DB, then create View(s) across the Fact(s) and all their joined Dimensions